# Getting multiple different values from a joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't figure out a good way of querying this without multiple sub-queries. I can't restructure the tables, so that's not an option. Here's the setup:

```
person:
person_id
person_want_id,
person_need_id,
person_ability_id,
person_willingness_id

person_status_types:
status_type_id
status_type_name
```

Each one of the id's that are in person is of type person_status_types. What I need to pull out is the status_type_name for each of the id's in person.

So the return statement would look like this:

```
person_id | person_want_name | person_need_name | person_ability_name | person_willingness_name
```

Right now I'm just doing 4 subqueries, but there has to be a cleaner way of doing it. Also, if you want to mention a better database structure, I'm open minded to it for future database production.

Comment: You could do four INNER JOINs on `person_status_types` with different aliases. I doubt there's much of a performance advantage to doing so, though.

Comment: The JOINS could in fact be slower in some situations, depending on how indexes are set up (or rather, not set up). I personally think the joins look a little cleaner, more manageable, but that's just me.

Comment: Compare plans with `explain analyze`. I won't be shocked if it turns out both approaches actually result in the same plan.

Comment: As for performance: For retrieving a single person, correlated subqueries may be equally fast or even slightly faster (but it won't matter much, because either is very fast for a single row). The more rows your query returns the greater is the performance gain by joining the tables instead of the correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT p.person_id
      ,want.status_type_name AS person_want_name
      ,need.status_type_name AS person_need_name
      ,abt.status_type_name  AS person_ability_name
      ,wil.status_type_name  AS person_willingness_name
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN person_status_types want ON p.person_want_id = want.status_type_id
LEFT JOIN person_status_types need ON p.person_need_id = need.status_type_id
LEFT JOIN person_status_types abt  ON p.person_ability_id = abt.status_type_id
LEFT JOIN person_status_types wil ON p.person_willingness_id = wil.status_type_id
```

Use `LEFT JOIN` to avoid loosing rows.
And you can't single-quote identifiers (like another answer suggests). Single quotes are for values.

#### Delimiter for identifier

Since this has sparked some debate, to clarify once and for all:

- **double quotes** `"` delimit *identifiers* according to any ANSI standard. This is *universally* supported by all RDBMS that matter, MySQL being the only exception. You can fix this in MySQL with `SET sql_mode = 'ANSI';`

  Some RDBMS accept additional alternative delimiters like `[]` for SQL server.
- **single quotes** `'` delimit *values* according to the ANSI standard. Some RDBMS (like MySQL or SQL Server) tolerate them them around column names as general string delimiters. Neither accepts them around table names though.
- **backticks** `´` as delimiter for identifiers are a MySQL oddity only. Again, you can fix this in MySQL with `SET sql_mode = 'ANSI';`

Here is a [list of databases and their respective delimiters for identifiers](http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/postgresql/identifiers#quoted_or_delimited_identifiers).

Comment: "And you can't single-quote identifiers" Are you sure about that, Erwin? You're right that you can't single-quote table aliases, but you can single-quote column aliases, else how would you alias a column as "my column name" (note the spaces)? Is this is difference specific to postgresql?

Comment: @ean5533: I am positive. Read more [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). And you are answering your question yourself again by using double-quotes. Correct: `"my column name"`. Incorrect: `'my column name'`.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me on this. I wasn't "answering my question" though by using double quotes, I was just trying to stick to the English language norm of using double-quotes to quote something.

Comment: After reviewing everyone's answers, I have successfully gotten it able to work! This cuts down on the amount of code that's there AND makes it easier to work with the tables I'm already having to work with. Thank you very much! BTW, tested the single quotes. That's why the check mark is here even though all the answers were correct.

Comment: @JasonMell: One more thing: for columns defined `NOT NULL` and with a foreign key constraint enforcing relational integrity, you can as well use `JOIN` (instead of `LEFT JOIN`), because it cannot fail then.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do subqueries, you can just do JOINs:

```
SELECT p.person_id, 
    want.status_type_name AS "person_want_name", 
    need.status_type_name AS "person_need_name", 
    ability.status_type_name AS "person_ability_name", 
    willingness.status_type_name AS "person_willingness_name"
FROM person p
JOIN person_status_types want ON p.person_want_id = want.status_type_id
JOIN person_status_types need ON p.person_need_id = need.status_type_id
JOIN person_status_types ability ON p.person_ability_id = ability.status_type_id
JOIN person_status_types willingness ON p.person_willingness_id = willingness.status_type_id
```

Note that the table aliases help you distinguish which "copy" of the table you're referencing, and that each one is joined on a different column from `person`.

**Edit**: The comments have identified that PostgreSQL does not allow single-quote for column aliases, which matches ANSI. Consider me surprised, since MySQL and SQL Server support it. My query has now been fixed.

Comment: As Erwin pointed out in his answer, this is incorrect. You cannot single-quote aliases as if they were literals; they're identifiers, and must be unquoted or double-quoted.

Comment: @CraigRinger Erwin is incorrect, at least on MySQL and SQL Server. You cannot use quotes on TABLE aliases, but you can (and **should**) on column aliases. After all, how else would you alias a column as "my column name" (note the spaces)? I realize the question mentions postgresql, but I would be shocked if postgresql deviated from this.

Comment: *single* quotes. PostgreSQL uses single quotes for literals and double quotes for identifiers. I was under the impression that was ANSI standard, but have not verified it.  OK, tested. PostgreSQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6e288/1 SQL Server, same schema and query, also fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e288/1 . MySQL: Also works with `ANSI` mode: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ff3e/2

Comment: @ean5533: Double-quotes *are* ANSI standard. And this is tagged [PostgreSQL]. And do you realize you are using *double*-quotes yourself?

Comment: @ean5533 These things are tricky, because many DBMSs are quite permissive. Figuring out the approach that works on all of them is tricky and can involve trial-and-error. MySQL allows SELECTing columns that didn't appear in a `GROUP BY` without an aggregate, so lots of people use that and then wonder why every other DBMS produces an error. Same deal. As for Oracle: it doesn't even run the standard SQL schema setup in the SQLFiddles above, it's a strange and quirky beast, nothing that it or MySQL do would surprise me. And SQL Server accepts `[identifier name]` for quoting, similarly weird...

Comment: I don't want to be a drag, but you introduced a new error with your update. Oracle does *not* support the non-standard single-quoted column aliases. [->sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/31c90/7) I added a chapter to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT person_id, st1.status_type_name AS want, st2.status_type_name AS need, st3.status_type_name AS ability, st4.status_type_name AS willingness
FROM person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN person_status_types st1 ON p.person_want_id=st1.status_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN person_status_types st2 ON p.person_need_id=st2.status_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN person_status_types st3 ON p.person_ability_id=st3.status_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN person_status_types st4 ON p.person_willingness_id=st4.status_type_id;
```