# Simple update trigger on PostgreSQL returning errors

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_status() RETURNS TRIGGER AS ' 
BEGIN 
SELECT status FROM animals
IF status = "Alive" 
THEN 
UPDATE animals SET status = "Sold" WHERE status="Alive";   
END IF;   
RETURN NULL; 
END; ' LANGUAGE plpgsql;  

CREATE TRIGGER updatetrigger AFTER UPDATE OF id_selling ON animals EXECUTE PROCEDURE     update_status();
```

It says I'm not using the selected attributes, and I should use Perform instead of Select. But then it doesnt recognize the IF after the perform. I'm really new to these syntax, so it might be wrong. I think its clear what I want to do (and i believe it simple for someone  with experience). Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Forgot to say its creating the trigger properly, the problem is when i update the id_selling variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In standard SQL (and PostgreSQL), this is a quoted identifier (table name, column name, ...):

```
"Alive"
```

and this is a string literal:

```
'Alive'
```

You will be getting complaints about "unknown columns" because you're using the wrong quotes for your strings.

Functions are usually defined with [dollar-quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) to avoid this sort of thing:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_status() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN 
    SELECT status FROM animals
    IF status = 'Alive' THEN 
        UPDATE animals SET status = 'Sold' WHERE status = 'Alive';   
    END IF;   
    RETURN NULL; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[Triggers have access to NEW and OLD](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/trigger-definition.html) to represent the previous/current state of the row and the new/updated state of the row, you should be consulting those instead of trying to SELECT to find the status:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_status() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.status = 'Alive' THEN 
        UPDATE animals SET status = 'Sold' WHERE status = 'Alive';   
    END IF;   
    RETURN NULL; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You might want a little more in the WHERE clause for that UPDATE too, just `WHERE status = 'Alive'` seems a bit broad.

Comment: I recently compiled a list for which delimiters to use for identifiers in [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13186974/939860).

Comment: This helped me a lot, TYVM! :)