# Grails naming id column Error

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, identifier, quoting

I'm having a problem in my domain class. Every time I try to insert an entry this error appears:

```
The column name "Sequence_No" was not found in this ResultSet.
```

Here is my domain class:

```
class Record {

String firstName
String middleName
String lastName
String motherMaidenLastName
String motherMaidenMiddleName
Date birthDate
String examTypeCode
Date examinationDate

static constraints = {
    firstName nullable:false, blank:false, maxSize: 50
    middleName nullable:true, blank:true, maxSize: 50
    lastName nullable:false, blank:false, maxSize: 50
    motherMaidenLastName nullable:true, blank:true, maxSize: 50
    motherMaidenMiddleName nullable:true, blank:true, maxSize: 50
    birthDate  nullable: false
    examTypeCode  nullable: false, maxSize: 4
    examinationDate  nullable: false
}

static mapping  = {
    datasource 'oevs'
    table '`elig`'
    id column: '`Sequence_No`'
    firstName column: '`FirstName`'
    middleName column: '`MiddleName`'
    lastName column: '`LastName`'
    motherMaidenLastName column: '`MotherMaidenLastName`'
    motherMaidenMiddleName column: '`MotherMaidenMiddleName`'
    birthDate column: '`Date_Birth`'
    examTypeCode column: '`ExamType`'
    examinationDate column: '`Date_Exam`'
    }
}
```

But the entry I tried to save is inserted in the database, it just throws that error. I'm using PostgreSQL. I was required to name the column names that way. That's why I need to place a back tick character in naming my columns because PostgreSQL automatically converts it all to lowercase letters if don't do that. Every time I remove the backtick character in my id column, the error doesn't show up but obviously the column name was converted to lowercase.

Comment: Are you using create-drop or update in your datasource? Have you checked the database schema?

Comment: yes, im using create-drop in my datasource.I've already checked the schema. It seems like the error is caused by the backtick character in the id column, everytime I remove the back tick on column id, all goes well. what confuses me is other property columns with back tick characters doesn't cause any error unlike in the id column.

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in this statement:

> That's why I need to place a back tick character in naming my columns
>   because PostgreSQL automatically converts it all to lowercase letters
>   if don't do that.

**Backticks (``)** are used in **MySQL** only (in pointless violation of the SQL standard - you can use `SET sql_mode = 'ANSI';` to fix this). Backticks have no special meaning to PostgreSQL or in standard SQL. Use **double-quotes(`""`) in PostgreSQL** (are anywhere, really) to achieve what you are aiming for. More details in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186974/939860).

You almost had it right: identifiers that are not *double-quoted* are cast to lower-case in PostgreSQL. Read the chapter [Identifiers and Key Words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in the manual for details.

I generally advice **not** to use CamelCase identifiers in PostgreSQL at all. There is many ways to trip over that. Desperate questions of confused users keep popping up here. Don't use CamelCase and never double-quote identifiers if you can. Once you create a non-standard identifier you have to double-quote that at all times ...

Comment: I tested it using **double-quotes("")** in my domain class, same thing happens.All of my declared columns except the id column in my __grails__ domain class with **backticks(``)** were successfully named  in CamelCase. I was required to name those columns that way, maybe I should recommend them naming the table columns in standard way like you said since I still don't konw how to solve this in __grails__.